# Launcher transparency

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

After messing around with CompizConfig I got to a state where I had to re-install lightdm, ubuntu-desktop and then re-enable all the compiz plugins.  Everything works great, but the launcher transparency doesn't do anything.  The launcher will change color depending on the wallpaper, but it stays at full opacity.  I also tried Unity-tweak-tool, and that didn't do anything either.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to remove any configuration you have done and start over. Below procedure will do that. You will not lose any personal files but you will lose any configuration you've done. (even the keyboard layout if any)

Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue the following commands

```
gconftool --shutdown
sudo killall -r -I gconf
sudo killall -r -I dconf
rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*
```

Reboot your PC.

Use a tool like `Unity Tweak Tool` and try to set the transparency of the Launcher. Do not use `ccsm` as it can destroy your desktop environment (little bit risky).