# How to enable the Unity plugin without ccsm

Tags: unity

I can only see my desktop pic upon login and that is because unity plugin isn't enabled.

I tried `ccsm`, but there is no way for me to apply changes so the unity plugin remains disabled. I also can't close windows because the bar at the top of each window is not there.

Comment: While [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/397027/95393) doesn't answer your exact question, might help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, every answer gets me closer to having unity working properly.

Comment: this couldn't solve my problem, but I will try to reinstall unity

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try. I have unchecked the Unity Plug-in. Windows decorations (title) disappeared, No windows switching, No Unity panel or launcher bar.

Try to re-enable the Unity plug-in no success (Check it, Go back and try again, it is still unchecked). Restarted gdm/lightdm, login again, same thing.

How it was fixed:

1. Using CompizConfiguration Setting Manager or `ccsm`
2. **Uncheck Gnome Compatibility** in General group.
3. Check again Ubuntu Unity Plugin in Desktop group.

Back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my new 14.04 installation, ccsm overwrote my unity plugin and it didn't appear in my ccsm plugin list. The following worked:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access tty. Log in.
2. Reinstall unity

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity
   sudo unity
   ```